# How to access shared posts with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app (in development mode) has gotten a User Access Token with manage_posts and user_posts from the administrator of a Page.

I want to GET the /sharedposts of a post of the Page to see who has shared the post.

I am trying to do this with the Access Token and with the Page Access Token I got from this user but I can only see the counts.

What kind of permissions do I need? I searched through all the documentation and it seems I have all permissions.

What if the Page Administrator used my app to publish the post? Then according to the documentation as I understand it I would be able to see the posts?

Note: I am using the facebook Graph API online interface so it's not a question of an error in the code.

Note2: It is not a duplicate of older posts, Facebook changed all their access controls in 2018 after breaches of security and this question needs a new answer.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert please don't vote for duplicate cause the answers there are from 2014 and Facebook recently changed everything in their access controls.

Comment: _“What kind of permissions do I need?”_ - you would need `user_posts` permission from the user that _made_ the post.

Comment: @misorude you mean the post the Page made, or the share action? The share action is what I want to get but I can't get permission from them, they are just reposting something from the page.

Comment: Permission from the user that shared your post onto their timeline. _“but I can't get permission from them”_ - then you can’t get the post they made either, simple as that.

Comment: @misorude but that doesn't make sense since the Page can see it and the Manager of the page can see it and I have the permission of both?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. Your little page admin clicking around a bit in the UI of their page is not going to do too much damage in regard to user privacy … but that one single app that gets used on thousands of pages, now that is a whole different story - name “Cambridge Analytica” still rings a bell, yes?

Comment: Would the Page Public Content Access allow my app then to see it? Or as the documentation says (if I don't misunderstand it) if my app creates the post? @misorude

Comment: No, PPCA would not allow this either. (That would only allow you access to the original page post, if you did not have admin access to the page.) I am not exactly sure about the post created by the app part - whether that refers to posts made via API (not possible any more to post in the name of a user via API), or if it includes shares made via the Share or Feed dialog (when initialized with the app id) would qualify as well. Guess you’d have to test it.